# Connecting to Azure Batch behind proxy - Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'

Tags: c#, azure, proxy

I've set up an Azure Batch account and am trying to use the C# HelloWorld example from here,

https://github.com/Azure/azure-batch-samples

After filling in the Batch and storage account details in AccountSettings.settings this works fine if I'm outside of my corporate network (which is behind a proxy server). However, when using the exact same code from behind the proxy server I'm getting,

```
BatchException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'
```

and in the console output the following,

```
C:\Source\Scratch\Azure-batch-samples\CSharp\GettingStarted\01_HelloWorld\bin\Debug>HelloWorld.exe
Running with the following settings:
-------------------------------------
PoolId = HelloWorld-Pool
PoolTargetNodeCount = 2
PoolOSFamily = 4
PoolNodeVirtualMachineSize = small
ShouldDeleteJob = True

BatchAccountName = <censored>
BatchAccountKey = <censored>
BatchServiceUrl = <censored>
StorageAccountName = <censored>
StorageAccountKey = <censored>
StorageServiceUrl = <censored>

Deleting job: HelloWorldJob-809362-20180126-143309
Microsoft.Azure.Batch.Common.BatchException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden' ---> Microsoft.Azure.
Batch.Protocol.Models.BatchErrorException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'
   at Microsoft.Azure.Batch.Protocol.JobOperations.<DeleteWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

<..snip..>

Request Information
ClientRequestId:
RequestId:d8b9fcc6-b32d-437c-a8af-7d44d6df486d
HttpStatusCode:Forbidden
StatusMessage:Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly
 including the signature.


Error Code = AuthenticationFailed, Lang=en-US, Message = Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value
of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:d8b9fcc6-b32d-437c-a8af-7d44d6df486d
Time:2018-01-26T13:33:13.9958126Z
Additional Values:
Error Details key=AuthenticationErrorDetail value=The MAC signature found in the HTTP request 'k4mfqD3FP6FL2nWLgR3E6AxRp
JJAse9vRW1qVOnn1K0=' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: 'DELETE
```

Does anyone know what's happening here?

Answer (score 2):

There appeared to be a [very similar issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/3170) that only affected .NET Core, but it was fixed in 7.0.1, and I assume you're using 8.0.1?

The first thing I would do is verify (using Fiddler or Wireshark) that the traffic is indeed going through the proxy you think it is.

If not, it might be worth trying the `BatchClient` ctor that takes a `BatchServiceClient` (creating an instance of `BatchServiceClient` by passing in an `HttpClientHandler` with the `Proxy` property set as required).

Failing that - do you actually *need* to access the batch services from behind the corporate proxy? My guess would be that whatever you want to actually do with the batch service will be wrapped in an API or web app that will itself be deployed to Azure - so no HTTP proxy required!